# Node.js Google Sheets API: can read but not create spreadsheet

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I have been working all day to try to get a Node.js application connected to my Google Drive to programmatically create spreadsheets using the Google Sheets API.

I think I have set up my connection correctly, because the following code block executes correctly:

```
/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
  let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
  if (client) {
    return client;
  }
  client = await authenticate({
    scopes: SCOPES,
    keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  });
  if (client.credentials) {
    await saveCredentials(client);
  }
  return client;
}

/**
 * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
 * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
 */
async function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
  const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
    range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
  });
  const rows = res.data.values;
  if (!rows || rows.length === 0) {
    console.log('No data found.');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Name, Major:');
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
    console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[4]}`);
  });
}

authorize().then(listMajors).catch(console.error);
```

As soon as I move from that code to the following code, I get 403 Insufficient Permission errors:

```
/**
 * Create a google spreadsheet
 * @param {string} title Spreadsheets title
 * @return {string} Created spreadsheets ID
 */
async function create(title) {
  const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
  const { google } = require('googleapis');

  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
  });

  const service = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
  const resource = {
    properties: {
      title,
    },
  };
  try {
    const spreadsheet = await service.spreadsheets.create({
      resource,
      fields: 'spreadsheetId',
    });
    console.log(`Spreadsheet ID: ${spreadsheet.data.spreadsheetId}`);
    return spreadsheet.data.spreadsheetId;
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
    throw err;
  }
}

authorize().then(create).catch(console.error);
```

I have tried this using OAuth2 Client ID, Service Account, and Application Default Credentials. I have enabled all Scopes for my application. I really don't understand what else it wants me to configure to tell it I can have access.

I am attempting to access an application created using my personal Gmail address by logging in using my personal Gmail address. When trying to use a Service Account, I created a new folder in Drive and gave it permissions.

I do not see any additional info in the [Create a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create) tutorial.

What other permission is it expecting me to grant and where?

Comment: See [Authorization Scopes of Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create#authorization-scopes)

Comment: Have you tried defining your scopes within the OAuth Consent Screen within the associated GCP Project for your web application? as mentioned by @idfurw above, the scopes needed are defined there on the article that was shared.

Comment: I did that, but it seems like it took several hours for that to finally show up. After retrying following a delay of a few hours, my Consent screen was updated and then my code sample worked to create a spreadsheet. Guess I just wasn't patient enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the application of my scopes took quite a bit longer than I anticipated. Once they were added to my application, the code worked correctly. I would estimate that it took 4-5 hours for the updates to finally show up.